# Singleton SharedPreferences with Dagger 2

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, mvp, dagger-2

I'm trying to create a Singleton of SharedPreferences using Dagger 2, and I keep getting the following error message:

> com.test.app.injection.component.ConfigPersistentComponent scoped with @com.test.app.injection.ConfigPersistent may not reference bindings with different scopes:
>   @Singleton class com.test.app.data.local.PreferencesHelper

I am trying to access shared preferences via Injected constructor in my MainPresenter. Using a Singleton DataManager for API access works fine via Injected constructor, but not for SharedPreferences.

Here is my setup:

AppModule

```
@Module(includes = {ApiModule.class})
public class AppModule {
    private final Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ApplicationContext
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreference(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

    Application application();

    DataManager apiManager();

    @ApplicationContext
    SharedPreferences prefManager(Context context);
}
```

ConfigPersistentComponent

```
/**
 * A dagger component that will live during the lifecycle of an Activity or Fragment but it won't be
 * destroy during configuration changes. Check {@link BaseActivity} and {@link BaseFragment} to see
 * how this components survives configuration changes. Use the {@link ConfigPersistent} scope to
 * annotate dependencies that need to survive configuration changes (for example Presenters).
 */
@ConfigPersistent
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface ConfigPersistentComponent {

    ActivityComponent activityComponent(ActivityModule activityModule);

    FragmentComponent fragmentComponent(FragmentModule fragmentModule);
}
```

ConfigPersistent

```
/**
 * A scoping annotation to permit dependencies conform to the life of the {@link
 * ConfigPersistentComponent}
 */
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConfigPersistent {
}
```

PreferencesHelper

```
@Singleton
public class PreferencesHelper {

    private final SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Inject
    PreferencesHelper(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        preferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    public void putString(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull String value) {
        preferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    public String getString(@Nonnull String key) {
        return preferences.getString(key, "");
    }

    public void putBoolean(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull boolean value) {
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(@Nonnull String key) {
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    }

    public void putInt(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull boolean value) {
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    public int getInt(@Nonnull String key) {
        return preferences.getInt(key, -1);
    }

    public void clear() {
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();
    }
}
```

MainPresenter

```
@ConfigPersistent
public class MainPresenter extends BasePresenter<MainMvpView> {

    private final PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;
    private final DataManager dataManager;

    @Inject
    public MainPresenter(PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper, DataManager dataManager) {
        this.preferencesHelper = preferencesHelper;
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Preseneter is in ConfigPersistent scope and SharedPreference is in Application scope, which is creating error, try injecting SharedPreference to a module.

Comment: I think you can also remove @ApplicationContext from your sharedpreferences provider method. I have a similar setup to what you are doing and it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Provides
@Singleton
// @ApplicationContext // <-- remove this
SharedPreferences provideSharedPreference(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

And add this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {    
    ...


    // @ApplicationContext
    SharedPreferences prefManager();

    PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper();
}
```